# Text file not being written, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getlink():
with open('findlink.txt') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "](":
            copy = True
        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)
        if line.strip() == ")":
            copy = False
            print("extractlink written.")
            infile.close()
            outfile.close()

def part3():
    with open ('findlink.txt', 'w') as findlink:
    findlink.write("[Testing](Test)")
    findlink.close() 
    print("findlink written and closed.")
getlink()

def run_bot():
    getlink() #Already have findlink.txt written
```

When part3() is activated, the text is written to findlink.txt as expected, but when getlink() is activated, the extractlink.txt is never written to.

I've gathered my current code from a post back in 2013/2016, does anyone have any ideas why this may not be working?

Comment: You have the same file open for reading and writing at the same time. That will  cause troubles.

Comment: Try to remove `findlink.close()` line and remove indent before  `getlink()`.

Comment: Your code is missing some pieces. It's impossible to help you as you have global variables we don't know the state of. Please check [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: @spectras, I'm not looking to share 60 lines of irrelevant code, is there anything in particular you need? I don't have any global variables.

Comment: Thanks @JonhyBeebop, It still not writing the text.

Comment: @KlausD. That is why I closed part(3) before getlink(), they shouldn't be running together, correct?

Comment: @Dansey if you don't have global variables, then the code will fail on `findlink.write(comment.body)`, since `comment` does not exist.

Comment: @spectras comment.body is from PRAW.

Comment: Still, it needs `comment` to exist and hold a PRAW comment. In the code you posted, `comment` does not exist at all, so that code will not run. Thus we cannot help you: perhaps the issue comes from the part of your code that sets it. We cannot see it so we cannot know.

Comment: @spectras I've provided a sample of the text located in comment.body

Comment: As you've insisted, despite my post not really deserving of the downvotes, I've added the full code, nothing changes.@spectras

Comment: Are you sure that your file "findlink.txt" has a line that contains only `](`?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a line that's not equal to `"]("` but contains this value. In that case `if line.strip() == "](":`is wrong and should be `if "](" in line:`.

Comment: @Matthias Such a simple error, I should have known better! :P Will try that out.

Comment: @Matthias that seems to copy the entire line rather than the value in between.

Comment: @Matthias Is there a code to copy just the text in between on one line?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
def getlink():
    with open('findlink.txt') as infile: 
        data = infile.readlines()

    with open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        copy = False
        for line in data:
            if line.strip() == "](":
                copy = True
            if copy:
                outfile.write(line)
            if line.strip() == ")":
                copy = False
                print("extractlink written.")
                outfile.close()
                extractlink()
                return
```